# undefined index in PHP

Tags: php

Tengo esto:

```
<form action="pelicula" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" value="'.$item["id"].'" id="id" name="id">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ver Pelicula"></a>
</form>
```

lo que quiero es que se pase el id a la pagina película, pero cuando doy click al botón, se ve por la url el parámetro pasado, pero la pagina película no lo recepciona al hacer `$_GET["id"]` no lo reconoce.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) echo '<div>'.$_GET['id'].'</div>';
$item['id']=11;
?>

<form method="get">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?=$item['id']?>" id="id" name="id">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ver Pelicula"></a>
</form>
```

Si omites el atributo `action` enviará el dato a la misma página desde la que envías el formulario, si quieres enviarlo a `pelicula`, debes darle la extensión del fichero. Y, sobre `value`, entiendo que el formulario lo tienes directamente en HTML, así que tendrás que meter el contenido de `$item['id']` con `<?=$item['id']?>`

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: el action si lo tengo hacia pelicula, el value en la url si se ve por ejemplo pagina.php?id=1 asi se ve pero si hago _GET["id] sale undefined id

Comment: En el código que te propongo, el `$_GET['id']` se muestra en pantalla, ¿qué estás probando para que falle?

Comment: Gracias a todos ya arregle el problema, lo que hice fue obtenerlo con javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes puesto mal el value, prueba a ponerlo

```
Value=" <?php echo $item["id"]; ?> "
```

Para que te ponga el valor o lo pones con echo o lo tienes que poner con `<?=`pero no lo puedes poner con un punto

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).